# Derived class object - Braced init

Tags: c++, c++11

In the below code,

```
struct X
{
  int a;
  int b;
  void *ptr;
};

class Base
{
 public:
  int a;
  int b;
  void *ptr;
};

class Child : public Base
{
public:
  int c;
};

X obj  = { 9, 2, malloc(TWOBYTES), };
Base obj1  = { 3, 4, malloc(TWOBYTES), };
Child obj2  = { 8, 4, malloc(TWOBYTES), 10, }; // Error
```

---

```
error: could not convert ‘{8, 4, malloc(2ul), 10}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Child’
   Child obj2  = { 8, 4, malloc(TWOBYTES), 10, };
                                               ^
```

---

`obj2` does not get initialised

**Question:**

Why braced-init syntax does not work for `Child` class?

Comment: In what order did you expect it to initialize `a`, `b`, `c` & `ptr` (and why)? In any case, this is not allowed *because the C++ standard says so*.

Comment: Don't use malloc in C++.

Comment: @manni66 `malloc()` should be used in C? Do we have C++ version of malloc()?

Comment: @overexchange make_unique, make_shared, vector, string or new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), for aggregate initialization to be legal a class cannot have a base class:

> *no virtual, private, or protected (since C++17) base classes*

`Child` obviously does have a base class (`Base`) and thus you get an error.

---

As also stated in the same link, this will be allowed in C++17 as long as the base class is not virtual, private or protected.

Comment: I have g++ version 5.4. Despite I give `-std=c++17` option, it invoke GNU C++14. Which version of g++ supports c++17 syntax?